# Is it secure to talk to a local API with http, when the public endpoint is https?

Tags: ssl, proxy

### Context

I have a server setup which looks like this:

- An Apache server is listening for `example.com`;
- Public port `80` is redirected to `443`;
- Public port `443` is forwarded to a Symfony project;
- On the same machine, there is a local API server written in Rust, which is listening to
  `http://127.0.0.1:8030` (*no SSL/TLS support*);
- The local API is able to respond some sensitive data, like JWT authentication tokens;
- `https://example.com/api` is a proxy to the local API server (`ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`,
  see the Apache config below), in order to:

  - expose the API to the final user *with SSL/TLS support*,
  - and to be able to send XHR javascript requests to it, from the public Symfony website.

*Note*: I made this setup with a proxy for the local API because I had many troubles with CORS rules; but
this is *not* the subject of my question (I guess there are far, far better setups).

### Question

Can this setup be considered as secure, or should it be a good point to add SSL/TLS support for the local API?

### Apache configuration, a bit simplified

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8030/
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:8030/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
    SSLCompression off
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/symfony_project/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/symfony_project/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/symfony_project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the permission for access to the host itself. In case the system is just handling http/https traffic and no users (except administrators) are allowed to login I would say YES it is secure design...

The question is WHO and WHEN can potentionally catch the sensitive data. The SSL termination is done on the server anyway so there is the part where the unsecured data exists anyway(e.g. RAM). So until the system is restricted to access and the unsecured data is not leaving the system  (e.g. not passing the network card) the data would be safe.

SSL layer on local connection would not have big benefit as all the keys are located on the system anyway. The resource saved on de-/crypting the local traffic can be used for the higher amount of connection the system can handle...